# Showing Dialog Message

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to angular.  I am developing a web page. In that when I click a dialog button it should prompt the heading message in `dialogComponent`. But, When I click the button it is prompting the dialog box, but it not showing the text which is in the `dialog.component.html`

Here is the `app.component.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog}  from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { DialogComponent } from "./dialog/dialog.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
constructor(public dialog:MatDialog){}
onCreate():void{
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    width:'290px',
    height:'300px',
    
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
   
  }
}
```

Here is `app.component.html` file

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()">Open Dialog</button>
```

Here is `dialog.component.html`

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Here is the `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DialogComponent } from './dialog/dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations"
import { MatButtonModule,MatCheckboxModule,MatTableModule } from "@angular/material"
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[DialogComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatTableModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The dialog box is showing like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROC9B.png)

Comment: can you edit the question & attach your `dialog.component.html` code properly?

Comment: Did you import `MatDialogModule` in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Yes, I imported.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the content with material directives(`mat-dialog-title` `mat-dialog-content` and `mat-dialog-actions` etc) read docs to get more information.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/epgpjvbnjbl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```